# Aikido locks/throws while wearing ken in the obi

Tags: aikido, technique, bokken

In some Aikido styles (I have seen this only from people who trained with Tamura, like Suga sensei, but maybe other schools do the same) there is a whole series of techniques where Tori slips the ken in the obi, in the way it was worn by Samurai in the past.

After having done that, Uke attempts a grab (either of the hand resting on the ken, or of the free hand) and Tori executes a "normal" technique, i.e. Ikkyo, Nikkyo, Kotegaeshi etc. But alwyas using the sword handle to supplement the technique (and often as part of the final lock on the ground).

Is there a technical (Japanese) word to name this type of forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @Sardathrion I was able to "deduce" the correct answer.

It is indeed Tachi Nage (as you can see here, for example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QRaylht6NNo) where Suga Sensei is performing a series of techniques while wearing a stheated sword in his Obi.

Alternatively also "SAYA NO UCHI" is a general term for this (saya means "Scabbard" - see also ["Saya no Uchi - principle and practice"](http://ichijoji.blogspot.de/2011/02/saya-no-uchi-principle-and-practice.html)).

Comment: You are welcome. ☺

Answer (score 2):

The closes I can think of is "tachi dori" although that is a set of techniques within the goshin no kata against bokuto, not with. Apart from that, I do not think there is a specific name to those. After all, they are just application of normal techniques.

Comment: Well, yes - tachi dori is usually the "defender" using the ken to throw/pin down the "attacker" (just like jo-dori). If we use jo as a reference this would be more like "tachi nage" but I never heard this so maybe it does not make sense or it is not the right term anyway.

Comment: Guess what? it is tachi nage, after all, thanks!